# My Android app is not responding to language change

Tags: android, localization

I have set up my app with string resources for 2 languages:  English & Indonesian.  When I change the language in the GUI Editor of Android Studio, my activities show the appropriate strings.  But when I change the language in the emulator or on an actual phone, my app doesn't use the Indonesian strings - only English.  The only exception to this is that I use a date widget, and it has text that does not come from my string resource.  That text gets translated just fine.

I'm pretty sure I had this working in an earlier stage of writing the app, but it sure isn't working now.

### I tried "cleaning" my project & doing a full build, but no change in the behavior.  What else can I try / look into?

New information:  when I change the language from the settings app within the emulator, only a few items in the settings app are changed.  Most of it is still English!  So maybe it's a problem in the emulator?

On my phone, I notice that everything in Settings gets translated...

Comment: I'd start examining whether the Indonesian resources end up in the APK. Do you have any `resConfig` optimizations in your build.gradle file?

Comment: I see 2 build.gradle files in my project - one is tagged with "(Module: app)" & the other with "(Project: MyApp)"  Neither of those files contain the word `resConfig`...  Is that a problem?

Comment: If it's not there, it is not the reason for this problem.

Comment: Therefore...?  Doesn't anyone have any ideas???

Comment: You might consider logging what `Locale` gives you (if your emulator is older than Android 7.0) or `LocaleList` (if your emulator is for Android 7.0+) for your app. Then, compare that with what you are using for the resource set qualifier (e.g., `-id`) for the string resources.

Comment: OK, I give up.  How do you get the Locale?  If I construct one, I have to give it the language (and optionally country & variant).  How do I get the Locale currently in use?  It doesn't seem to be available via context or view...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in some prior version of the SKD the code for Indonesian was 'id', but then changed to 'in'.  As I mentioned in the original post, I had this working in a prior state of the app, but then it stopped working.  This is probably due to my changing minSDKVersion at some point to 21 from some earlier version.

I was able to confirm the correct code for Indonesian language by following CommonsWare's advice and accessing the Locale.  After some research, I found out the way to do this in my app is:

```
Locale lTemp = getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
String sTemp1 = lTemp.getCountry();
String sTemp2 = lTemp.getLanguage();
```

Note that getConfiguration().locale is deprecated, the preferred method is:

```
Locale lTemp = getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
```

but in order to use this method, I would have had to change minSDKVersion to 24, which I was unwilling to do.